# Does TypeScript support synonymous interface properties?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a TypeScript interface for an options object that allows different keys (synonyms) to represent the same property. Adding the properties separately, like

```
interface CustomOptions {
    ...
    uri:string;
    url:string;
    URI:string;
    URL:string;
    ...
}
```

causes the compiler to raise errors if only one of the synonyms gets defined.

Is there a way to define synonymous interface properties? Something like, for example,

```
interface CustomOptions {
    ...
    uri|url|URI|URL:string;
    ...
}
```

Comment: No this
 not possible.

Comment: You can make a union type like `type CustomOptions = ({ uri: string } | { url: string } | { URI: string } | { URL: string }) & { yourOtherProps... }` but... why would you want to support that?  TypeScript and IntelliSense makes discovery of a single key name like `uri` easy enough, and a type without these key synonyms is much simpler.  It doesn't seem worth the complexity.  Can you demonstrate a compelling use case?

Comment: Thanks for the information. @jcalz: The use case is not compelling: For users/developers whose IDE does not support TypeScript IntelliSense, I wanted to add some tolerance when defining the properties of the given options object.

Comment: I can understand that, but don't such users need to consult some sort of documentation to even know that there is a URL-like property to set?  And that documentation would say `uri: a string representing the URL of the blah blah` and that's that.  Encouraging haphazard use of your library is probably going to backfire on you ("I don't understand why I can't pass `{Url: ""}` or `{uRi: ""}`?  Why did it only choose the second property when I passed in `{URL: "/a", url: "/b"}`? etc etc)

Comment: @jcalz: I fully agree with you. It is a habit from times where only a small portion of the code produced by our development team had been documented. It was helpful to tolerate different argument constellations or property synonyms because it reduced the number of times you had to directly look it up in the code. Now that our code base (JS) has grown quite large, and more and more developers work on it, it has become necessary to switch to a solid system. I'm quite new to TypeScript, but it seems like that'll do :)